# how to count zgc result(gc time and heap usage)

Tags: java, garbage-collection, zgc

the result of `jstat -gcutil` is suitable for generational garbage collection, but how can I count the zgc result?

Answer (score 0):

afaik, every GC algorithm implements its own statistics, meaning that is a collector specific output. Yes, `ZGC` is not generational, as such some of the statistics will not be present, which is normal, but otherwise it simply works?

If I have a sample as :

```
 public class DeleteMe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(;;){
            LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(500));
            System.out.println(allocate());
        }
    }

    static int allocate() {
        int [] b = new int[10_000];
        for(int i=0;i<10_000;++i){
            b[i] = i + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt();
        }
        return Arrays.hashCode(b);
    }

}
```

And then take some snapshots of :

```
jstat -gcutil <PID>
```

I do see numbers like:

```
  S0     S1     E      O      M     CCS    YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT    CGC    CGCT     GCT   
   -      -      -  15.38  76.33  74.80      -        -     -        -    63    0.005    0.005
```

`S0/S1/E` are blank because they simply don't exist (there is no young generation at all). Same argument stays true for: `YGC/YGCT/FGC/FGCT`, simply because there is no such thing in `ZGC`. You can find what they mean [here, for example](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/tools/jstat.html). There is also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55803602/whats-the-meaning-of-cgc-and-cgct-in-jdk11-jstat-gc-pid) that explains some options that are not present in the documentation above.

Comment: I can see the change of old generation, but the GCT is always 0   S0     S1     E      O      M     CCS    YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT    CGC    CGCT     GCT
     -      -      -  22.71  98.44      -      -        -     -        -     -        -    0.000
     -      -      -  23.16  98.44      -      -        -     -        -     -        -    0.000
but acordding to the gc log, gc happens very often

Comment: @nzomkxia let it run more or allocate more, then you will see results there.

Comment: I'm doing a stress testing now, gc log shows it happens(with gc,start symbol) at intervals of five seconds, and I can see the change of  "O" colum, but "GCT keeps 0

Comment: this is how I ran it `java -XX:+UseZGC -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -Xmx25m -Xms25m DeleteMe.java`, on jdk-15.

Comment: I've try your Demo with JDK11 on linux, but the GCT is still 0